# Como fazer Slider Materializecss redimensionar altura em conformidade aos dispositivos

Tags: css, materialize

Gostaria de fazer o slider do Materialize Css que tem por padrão altura de 400px em todos os tamanhos responsivos.

Gostaria que esta altura tenha sua altura alterada conforme o dispositivo.

Estou usando o seguinte código CSS

```
.slider .slides {
    margin: 0;
    height: 400px;
}

.slider .slides li img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Veja imagem abaixo que ilustra o problema.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Precisa usar `media query`, mas se você quer que por exemplo o slider tenha metade da altura da tela, pode usar `50vh`

Comment: Isto mesmo @Guilherme Costamilam poderia postar o exemplo, estou precisando disto mesmo

Comment: `media query` ou `vh`?

Comment: Viu posta os dois se der, ja usei media query e vh nunca usei, gostaria de saber o que é vh, vou procurar me informar o que é vh, posta os dois se der amigo, MAS de preferencia media query que tenho mais afinidade.

Comment: Qual versão do Materialize vc está usando

Comment: Estou utilizando Release: 1.0.0

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam pode postar ai somente media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Media Querys](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries) servem para determinar um estilo para uma determinada situação (por exemplo, tamanho específico de tela, orientação, entre outros)

Para os tamanho da tela, geralmente se usa esses breakpoints:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...} 

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...} 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...} 

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

O Materialize usa breakpoints diferenes, de uma olhada na seção [Creating Responsive Layouts](https://materializecss.com/grid.html)

Um exemplo de uso:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
  var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, {});
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .carousel-item {
    height: 100px !important;
  }
}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .carousel-item {
    height: 200px !important;
  }
}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-item {
    height: 300px !important;
  }
}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .carousel-item {
    height: 400px !important;
  }
}

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .carousel-item {
    height: 500px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="carousel">
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
</div>

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```